# Java IF statements not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

There is some problem with my if statements. Error shows this 
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbYGj.jpg)
Could you help me figure out what's wrong with it ? The main task is that a motor insurance company has 4 categories of insurance based on the age and gender of the applicant.

this is the code :

```
String gender, age;
char group;
int genderint, ageint;
gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please specify your gender(1 for male, 0 for female)");
age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your age");
genderint = Integer.parseInt(gender);
ageint = Integer.parseInt(age);
if (gender = 0 || 1 && age = > 18 && < 26) {
    group = "Category A";
} else if (gender = 0 && age = > 27 && < 60) {
    group = "Category B";
} else if (gender = 1 && age = > 27 && < 60) {
    group = "Category C";
} else if (gender = 0 || 1 && age = > 60) {
    group = "Category D";
} else if (gender = 0 || 1 && age = < 18) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you're too young");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have been assignet to" + group);
}
}
```

Comment: Whoever told you that you can write boolean expression like this `gender = 0 || 1` is someone you should not listen to anymore.

Comment: @Tom
I just started college and I just tend to forget some things.. I need to practice more.

Comment: Well, then keep listening to your teachers ;P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

- use `==` for comparison
- no space between `<=` and `>=`
- group `or` conditions in parenthesis
- use separate variable for each comparison
- use `<=` not `=<`, use `>=` instead of `=>`
- use `genderint` and `ageint` variables for int comparison

  ```
  if ((genderint == 0 || genderint ==1) && (ageint >=18 && ageint < 26)) {
      group = "Category A"; 
  } else if(genderint == 0 && ageint >= 27 && ageint < 60){
      group = "Category B"; 
  } else if(genderint == 1 && ageint >= 27 && ageint < 60) {
      group = "Category C"; 
  } else if((genderint == 0 || genderint == 1) && ageint >= 60) {
      group = "Category D";
  } else if((genderint == 0 || genderint ==1) && ageint <18){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, you're too young"); 
  }
  ```

Comment: @mynawaz Please recheck how one should compare strings.

Comment: So i changed 1 thing in your code and its working perfectly. Before it said that string cannot be converted to char but now its grand ? :D
         `if ((genderint == 0 || genderint ==1) && (ageint >=18 && ageint < 26)) {
  group = 'A'; 
} else if(genderint == 0 && ageint >= 27 && ageint < 60){
  group = 'B'; 
} else if(genderint == 1 && ageint >= 27 && ageint < 60) {
    group = 'C'; 
} else if((genderint == 0 || genderint == 1) && ageint >= 60) {
    group = 'D';
} else if((genderint == 0 || genderint ==1) && ageint <18){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, you're too young"); 
}`

Comment: Cool, yes it was my bad that i missed that `String` variables are being compared to `int` values

Comment: Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 1):

First things first...

1. Replace `= >` with `>=` , `=<` with `<=` and `=` with `==` (when comparing gender) in if conditions.
2. Gender is `string` and in java string is compared by `.equals()` not by '=='.

Comment: Such a rookie mistake.. wow. Thank you :D
Although the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues there:

- `= <` operator is written `<=` (no space, `=` after `<`); same goes for `= >` (i.e. `>=`)
- `gender = 0 || 1` needs to be `genderint == 0 || genderint == 1`
- `age = >27 && <60` should be `age >= 27 && age < 60`

Comment: @Tom That's right, thanks. OP's got `genderint`, but he never uses it.

Comment: I have fixed what you gave me. Some errors are still there.

Comment: @Duzy Did you spot the `gender` -> `genderint` edit?

Comment: Yes, I have changed this also ageint. Thank you. Problem still there ._.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be using `genderint` and `ageint` in your conditions.

Second of all, you seem to be inventing some operators that don't exist :

- `gender = 0 || 1` should be `(genderint == 0 || genderint == 1)` - comparison requires `==`
- `age = >18 && <26` should be `ageint >= 18 && ageint < 26` - greater than or equal is `>=`

Answer (score 0):

```
    //gender is string
    if ((gender.equals("0") || gender.equals("1")) && (ageint >= 18 && ageint < 26))
    {
        //group is string
        group = "Category A";
    }
```